# Search list of unique _id as String in mongoDB with find()

Tags: java, mongodb

I would like to find a list of different values with unique _id but the problem is that they are saved as String and if I try to search f.e 10 it finds me also 100, 101, 102 etc..
In my case `{ "_id" : { "$gte" : "10" , "$lte" : "15"}}` I would like to find 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15. But it finds me also 100, 110, 120 etc..

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two more options:

- Issue a `$regex` query: `{_id : /^1[0-5]/}` (not sure about the PCRE syntax)
- Add a new field whose value is the numeric equivalent of `_id` and query that new field

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using javascript expression

```
db.test.find("this._id > 10 && this._id < 15")
```

Please note that this will be a little slower

Comment: Java, not Javascript.

Comment: @DJClayworth Please corrct me if I am wrong. I think the answer I poster is Javascript itself and not Java. Please take a look at this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where